# Python script not executing (No module named APNSWrapper)

Tags: python

In the terminal I run this command:

```
Python pnot.py

I get the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pnot.py", line 1, in <module>
    from APNSWrapper import *
ImportError: No module named APNSWrapper
```

I have tried to install the module:

```
pip install APNSWrapper==0.6.1

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): APNSWrapper==0.6.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): docutils>=0.3 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages (from APNSWrapper==0.6.1)
Cleaning up...
```

I have tried to install APNS:

```
Pip install apns
```

I get the following error:

```
Downloading/unpacking apns
  Downloading apns-1.1.2.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package apns

Installing collected packages: apns
  Running setup.py install for apns
    error: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/__pycache__/apns.cpython-33.pyc: Permission denied
    Complete output from command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/python3.3 -c "import setuptools;__file__='/private/var/folders/8g/6w73vzqs04b6f1cq8m8pyswc0000gn/T/pip_build_samiesyed/apns/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/8g/6w73vzqs04b6f1cq8m8pyswc0000gn/T/pip-3yfn_n-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed:
    running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib

copying apns.py -> build/lib

running install_lib

copying build/lib/apns.py -> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages

byte-compiling /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/apns.py to apns.cpython-33.pyc

error: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/__pycache__/apns.cpython-33.pyc: Permission denied

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/python3.3 -c "import setuptools;__file__='/private/var/folders/8g/6w73vzqs04b6f1cq8m8pyswc0000gn/T/pip_build_samiesyed/apns/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/8g/6w73vzqs04b6f1cq8m8pyswc0000gn/T/pip-3yfn_n-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/8g/6w73vzqs04b6f1cq8m8pyswc0000gn/T/pip_build_s/apns
Storing complete log in /Users/s/.pip/pip.log
```

script code:

```
from APNSWrapper import *

wrapper = APNSNotificationWrapper('cert.pem', True)
for token in ['xxxxxxx']:
    token = binascii.unhexlify(token)
    apn = APNSNotification()
    apn.token(token)
    alert = APNSAlert()
    alert.body('hello world')
    apn.alert(alert)
    apn.sound()
    wrapper.append(apn)
wrapper.notify()
```

This is really frustrating me, not sure why the script is not executing.

Comment: if you are running on linux try `sudo pip install apns`

Comment: running it mac - mavericks. Cheers.

Comment: Don't do sudo pip, ever: http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/09/16/recommended-way-for-sudo-free-installation-of-python-software-with-virtualenv/

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa Your article says: `"... and sudo pip are something you should do very seldom"`, not never.

Comment: This is definitely an instance where you should not use pip to install anything to your system packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely `pip` and `python` point to different Python installations. One might be from package manager, one might be from the system defaults.

You can find this out by doing commands

`which python`

`which pip`

Probably pip installs packages against some other python installation you are trying to use.

The solution to the problem, no matter how it has manifested itself, is to use `virtualenv` environments for your Python package installations. `virtualenv` creates a self-contained folder containing the python interpreter and package installations, which you can wipe clean and rebuild in the case of problems.

First install virtualenv.

Then do:

```
 virtualenv venv   # Create virtualenv installation in folder called venv
 source venv/bin/activate  # Modify your shell and PATH to use python from venv/bin/python
 pip install apns  # Installs apns in venv/lib
 python pnot.py   # Now it runs your script using venv/bin/python interpreter 
 # and packages installed in venv/lib/python2.7
```

More information about python and virtualenv installations

- http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/09/16/recommended-way-for-sudo-free-installation-of-python-software-with-virtualenv/

Comment: This was the problem - 2 versions of python was installed.